# mongoose findOne returns undefined

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a method "GenerateTokenString()" that generates a random key after creating the key i passed it to a function IsTokenExists but this function returns undefines although their is a key exists in the database.

```
key = GenerateTokenString();

            //Check if key already exists
            var isExists=IsTokenExists(key) //undefined

function IsTokenExists(key){
     Token.findOne({token:key}).then(doc=>{
         console.log(doc)
         return doc
     }).catch(err=>{
         console.log(err)
         return err
     })
    }
```

Comment: can you try using `await` before `var isExists= await IsTokenExists(key)` in `async` function.

Comment: async function GenerateToken()
    {
        var key="";
        try
        {
            key = GenerateTokenString();

            //Check if key already exists
            var isExists=await IsTokenExists(key)//undefined

Comment: still undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to return a value from `then` to the function `IsTokenExists` but you don't use it to return it from `IsTokenExists`:

```js
//Check if key already exists
try {
  var isExists = await IsTokenExists(key) //undefined
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}

async function IsTokenExists(key){
  return Token.findOne({token:key})
}
```